# Django random css names

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

I want the background color to change every time with Django. For example: bg-success, bg-primary, bg-light, bg-dark... etc. and just randomly. How can I do?

```
<div class="bg-success">

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just use python builtin module `random.choice`:

views.py:

```
def index(request):
    randomclass = random.choice(['bg-success', 'bg-primary', 'bg-light', 'bg-dark'])
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'randomclass': randomclass})
```

index.html

```
<div class="{{ randomclass }}">
</div>
```